# Python and SQLite storing variables

Tags: python, sqlite

If I the following code, how do I insert my string 'test' into the database

```
connection = connect(database = 'orders.db')
orders_db = connection.cursor()

test = 'Product 1'

sql = """INSERT INTO `CustomerOrders`(Product) VALUES(?)"""
orders_db.execute(sql)

connection.commit()

orders_db.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it !

> (test,)  here the comma is required ,without it the intrepreter will
>   throw an error since it takes each characters as an argument!

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(database = 'orders.db')
connection.execute('''Create table if not exists CustomerOrders(Product Varchar(100))''')
orders_db = connection.cursor()

test = 'Product 1'

sql = """INSERT INTO CustomerOrders(Product) VALUES(?)"""
orders_db.execute(sql,(test,))

connection.commit()

orders_db.close()
connection.close()
```